# Alpha in pyqt stylesheet slowly goes to 100%

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am writing a program in pyqt and I call `self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0,0,200,20)")`, thinking that, as the qt documentation says, "style sheets offer guarantees: If you set the background color of a QPushButton to be red, you can be assured that the button will have a red background in all styles, on all platforms." [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html#overview).

Unfortunately, when I click on the window, the alpha slowly goes up to 100% (no transparency). I have one widget (a push button), and I call the following:
`button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background: "+str(color)+"}" "QPushButton:pressed {background-color: "+str(clicked)+"}")` to se the background color transparent (Color and clicked are stings that say "transparent", so they should make the button background transparent).

So my question is: is there any reason why the transparency would disappear? And how can I be sure the alpha levels stay? (Note: I know I can make the window completely transparent with `Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground`)
Helpful info: Windows 8.1 python 2.7.8 qt4 
Any ideas? Is this a bug? Am I doing this wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what's the exactly format of your QSS value? so far as I know, the Qt internal may have some default handling ways to handle the QSS style, so not proper new line indicator may get this not work. Have you tried other platform instead of Win8.1?

Comment: For me it works. I see a transparent background color of the button. My config: Win7, Python3.4, PySide 1.2.2, Qt 4.8

Comment: @Trilarion and CuiHeng, thanks. I think I may have found the problem. I have a button method that is called by my main window. It should be passed a color, but in my call of the method I left it out. I set the button to now call transparent. I don't have the hardware to test this right now, but I will when I do. Could this be my problem? The button seems to take a hint from the window and be transparent (not in my code). Could this cause the deterioration.

Comment: @IronManMark20 I do not know but why not posting a full example showing the error and we can help you much easier.

Comment: @Trilarion I just posted it to a [Github](https://github.com/IronManMark20/PyStart). You can look at it/download it/debug it based on that. I tried making the variables constants, but that didn't really help.

Comment: @IronManMark20 I played around with your script but apart from an error (windll.dwmapi.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(c_int(self.winId()), byref(c_int(-1)))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type PyCapsule)) there are so many things going on that any of that can have a side effect. I recommend making the example easier and easier until transparency of the button stays.

Comment: @Trilarion I think I will just use the WA_TranslucentBackground. I have been trying every point where I use style sheets, and still nothing has worked. I have had no success at all. By the way, when I take the ctypes out, I just get a black background for the main window.